# Get latest Associated Work Items for Git Commit using TFS REST API

Tags: git, api, tfs

I'm trying to get the associated Work Items of a [GIT Commit using the TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits).

My request URL looks like this:

http://tfs.server:8080/tfs/X/Y/_apis/git/repositories/GettingStarted.UI/commits/80186d385522150ee43ca85891fef565f37518df?api-version=3.0

In the response I have found the related work items appended to the Comment:

"comment": "Merged PR 4357: Corrected format of FEIN in client header\n\nCorrected format of FEIN in client header\n\n**Related work items: #539077**"

However, when a new Work Item is associated to the Git Commit the comment is not updated with it. Is there a way to get the current associated Work Items in a structured way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you got is the correct situation. Git commits can be linked to work items for several ways. From the Pending Changes window, work items can be added using the UI features or by adding a mention to the commit comment in the form of “**#ID**” where ID is the work item ID.

According to your comment, *work item 539077* is linked to the commit during the pending change either with #ID or through UI. However, when a new work item is also associated to the same Git Commit either through  work item UI or Rest API. **The new linked work item will not update in the commit comment.**

Unless you update the comment of the commit, the result of comment will not change when you query a GIT Commit using the TFS REST API.

For a new Work Item  associated to the Git Commit, you could only be able to query the new work item toe get the commit ID, not able to query the commit to get new work item ID.

Comment: This is unfortunate. I'm building a tool to track application changes and for TFS Changesets I can get all related work Items through the .NET TFS API based on a ChangesetId. I don't understand why there couldn't be a way to get all associated Work Items for a GIT Commit in a RESTful way or any other structured way other than appending the Work Items it to the Comment (One time operation). I think when a user links a Git Commit to a WI through Visual Studio portal it should update the comment automatically.

Comment: @AdolfoPerez, Yes, you could also get all related work items  of changeset through [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#with-work-items),  should return `"workItems": [
    {
      "webUrl": "http://xxi:8080/tfs/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=3d4361f8-6de1-4725-8c7e-eac1c39bd8bc&id=2701",
      "id": 2701,
    },
    {
      "webUrl": "http://xxi:8080/tfs/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=3d4361f8-6de1-4725-8c7e-eac1c39bd8bc&id=2703",
      "id": 2703, `unlike changeset, there is no such rest api for git commit now, and the return of  commit not include work item part.

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT. My issue is not fixed. I'm still not able to get the current related work Items out of a Git Commit. If related WI's are always placed in comments I would think that Visual Studio web portal should update the comment when linking to another WI. I appreciate your help but cannot mark it as answer for this same reason.

Comment: @AdolfoPerez You cannot update a Git commit comment. Doing so actually creates a new Git commit, which means you are rewriting public commits. This is a big deal and is generally avoided at all cost.