# How can one fetch work items associated with a Git commit in Azure DevOps using the REST Api?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

My question is related to [Get latest Associated Work Items for Git Commit using TFS REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957937/get-latest-associated-work-items-for-git-commit-using-tfs-rest-api) which is more than 1 year old.

I too want to get all the work items associated with a Git Commit. Could not find the respective API. But 1 year is a lot of time, maybe it exists now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API with optional parameter `searchCriteria.includeWorkItems=true`, you will get the all commits with their associated work items.

For example:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/commits?searchCriteria.includeWorkItems=true&?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Results (you will get all commits, you can filter the results with PowerShell):

```
  "commitId": "60a69554c80839d631e77ea0exxxxxxxxxxx",
  "author": {
    "name": "Shayki Abramczyk",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "date": "2018-10-11T14:27:55Z"
  },
  "committer": {
    "name": "Shayki Abramczyk",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "date": "2018-10-11T14:27:55Z"
  },
  "comment": "Updated README.md",
  "changeCounts": {
    "Add": 0,
    "Edit": 1,
    "Delete": 0
  },
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/shaykia/7fcdafd5-b891-4fe5-b2fe-xxxxxxxxxx/_apis/git/repositories/815cc0c7-5f3e-404b-8fd7-xxxxxx/commits/60a69554c80839d631e77eaxxxxxxxx",
  "remoteUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/shaykia/xxxxxxx/_git/GitSample/commit/60a69554c80839d631e77ea0ed8bxxxxxxxx",
  "workItems": [
    {
      "id": "18",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/shaykia/_apis/wit/workItems/18"
    }
  ]
},
```

Unfortunately, this option does not exist in the [Get (one) Commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API.

Comment: I should be able to pass the `searchCriteria.ids` equal to one commit Id.

Comment: I checked now, if I pass a commit I didn't get the work items :/

Comment: You can filter them easily with PowerShell/C#/Python etc.

Comment: But the server still fetches all the commits. This is not a scalable approach.